# Can I get South Korean visa on my way to the US?

Tags: study, south-korea, pakistani-citizens, visas-on-arrival, us-visa

I am Pakistani national and was student in Japan. Now for further studies I am moving to the US. I have US student visa now. I am traveling from Japan and I have layover at Inchen Airport, Seoul for about 18 hours. Can I get the South Korean visa on arrival? It is long time for layover, I can't stay in transit area that long and I will like to go out.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a visa in order to transit Incheon airport, as long as your connection is less than 24 hours.  However as a Pakistan citizen you will NOT be allowed exit the international transit area of the airport.

Your only option if you wish to exit the airport would be to obtain a tourist visa in advance.  There are no options for obtaining one one arrival in South Korea.

Comment: Korea has a transit tourist program allowing for a 30 day entry, but Pakistani nationals unfortunately aren't eligible. There's also a 72-hour transit entry, but again it looks like Pakistani nationals aren't eligible.

Comment: Timatic only refers to the 24hr TWOV scheme, remaining in the transit area. According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea) Pakistanis, along with a number of other nationalities, are specifically excluded from the various exemptions.

Comment: Yup, that's why I said their only option was to get a visa...